# Display RSS Feed or API on Vue application

Tags: javascript, api, express, vue.js, rss

I've been trying this for months.

I wish to display the following RSS Feed on my vue.js application: https://www.google.ie/alerts/feeds/10663948362751557705/4511034072220974544.

But how do I link all of the below together and display the series of articles? I am struggling here and any help would be appreciated!

I have setup a back end to avoid CORS policy in Express.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Test'
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on ${port}`);
});
```

GoogleAlert Component:

```
<template>
  </template>

<script>
  export default {

  };
</script>
```

PostArticles.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:4000';

export default {
mounted() {
  axios.get('https://www.google.ie/alerts/feeds/10663948362751557705/16000017647453347583')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
  console.log(response);
  })
 .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
   console.log(error);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your backend gives permission, using CORS, for any origin to read data from it.

Your frontend is asking for the RSS data *directly from Google*. It isn't going anywhere near your backend.

*Google* aren't using CORS to give your frontend permission to read its data.

You need to change your frontend so it asks your backend for the data, and you need to change your backend so it provides the frontend with that data (which will mean having the backend fetch it from Google (and likely keep a local cache of it)).

Comment: Thanks. Problem is I don't know how to do this.

Comment: As @Quentin suggests, your Node code has to make the request to Google, then output the result. You can use HTTP in Node various ways, I'd suggest node-fetch, but at the end, you want to be able to hit your Node code's URL and ensure it outputs the RSS. Once that is done, your front end points to the Node server's URL.

Basically - research how to make a HTTP request in Node, it's fairly simple, and then you're basically done. :)